# AngularJS ng-click inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a ng-click nested inside a ng-repeat, and I am trying to pass a value from the current item in the loop. If I inspect the html generated using Chrome developer tools it looks correct (&ID=1) but when I put a break point in the function it shows &ID={{d.ID}} as the value that gets passed to the function.
Any help is appreciated.

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="d in data">
    </td>
    <td> 
        <a href="#" ng-click="openDialog(false,'http://portal.sharepoint.com/Lists/Organization/DispForm.aspx?IsDlg=1&ID={{d.ID}}')"> {{d.OrganizationName}}</a> 
    </td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: Have you tried to change ng-click for onclick? I think it will solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it:

```
 <tr ng-repeat-start="d in data">
            </td>
            <td> 
                <a href="" ng-click="openDialog(false,'http://portal.sharepoint.com/Lists/Organization/DispForm.aspx?IsDlg=1&ID='
+d.ID)"> {{d.OrganizationName}}</a> 
            </td> 
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend passing the Id in as an attribute of the openDialog method and building the url string in the controller.

```
ng-click="openDialog(false,'http://portal.sharepoint.com/Lists/Organization/DispForm.aspx?IsDlg=1', d.ID)"
```

then build the string in the controller and perform your location change. Easier to debug and un-clutters the view.

you could also store this string in your controller 'http://portal.sharepoint.com/Lists/Organization/DispForm.aspx?IsDlg=1'

```
ng-click="openDialog(false, d.ID)"
```

Answer (score 0):

ngClick directive will evaluate an expression. I guess it's not what you want

Try to change ng-click by simple onclick. It will solve your problem:

Change

```
 <a href="#" ng-click="openDialog(false,'http://portal.sharepoint.com/Lists/Organization/DispForm.aspx?IsDlg=1&ID={{d.ID}}')"> {{d.OrganizationName}}</a>
```

for

```
 <a href="#" onclick="openDialog(false,'http://portal.sharepoint.com/Lists/Organization/DispForm.aspx?IsDlg=1&ID={{d.ID}}')"> {{d.OrganizationName}}</a>
```

With ng-click. you don't need to use {{}} in order to get the variable value. Like in this sample from [Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick)

```
<button ng-click="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0">
  Increment
</button>
<span>
  count: {{count}}
</span>
```